# Providing a default value as function for a template

Tags: c++, c++11

When i use following as say `Event<void()>` it works fine. But now i like to have default template value so i change following to `template<class _Fty = void()>` so i can have `Event<> aEvent`. But it seem to fail with bunch of errors.

```
template<class _Fty>
struct Event final {
    typedef std::function<_Fty> listener_type;
    ...
}
```

Can anyone suggest how can accomplish what i want as describe above?

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::_Get_function_impl<_Fty>'
        with
        [
            _Fty=void (__cdecl *)(void)
        ]
C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\functional(1479): note: see declaration of 'std::_Get_function_impl<_Fty>'
        with
        [
            _Fty=void (__cdecl *)(void)
        ]
```

Comment: `template<class _Fty = void()>` --> `template<class _Fty = void>`. Also, names like `_Fty` are reserved for the implementation and you shouldn't use them.

Comment: @cigien Gives different error  `error C2027: use of undefined type std::_Get_function_impl<_Fty>'
        with
        [
            _Fty=void
        ]`

Comment: Ok, then please make a [mre]

Comment: Unrelated note: Any identifier starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved in C++. This shouldn't be related to your issue, but you should consider renaming the template parameter to just `Fty` instead of `_Fty`

Comment: [Works fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e289623ba23631ac). Show your complete code as this example is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might as well know all the underscore rules, so [here's a link to a broader explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) of the problem Human-Compiler raised.

Comment: You say you defined the default to be `_Fty = void()`, but the error message says you wrote `_Fty = void (*)()`. What you said you did would have been correct, but what you appear to have done is not. [Take a look](https://godbolt.org/z/bKzcj5).

Comment: @Human-Compiler _Fty funny as it is, it might. Apparently _Fty is a used identifier in at least one compiler: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/165660/error-c2027-use-of-undefined-type-std-get-function.html

Comment: @SergeyA Ha, nice, that explains the OP's error message :) Might be the first time I've seen a reserved name actually conflict. Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Thanks for the info about underbar.

Comment: @HTNW on the online compile pasting my code does not give any error and i do have that `void()`. It compile fine. The exact code fail to compile on my box. I have VS2017.

Comment: See, the comments. Using `_Fty` invokes undefined behavior. Change the name.

Comment: Thank you guys, at least i know nothing is wrong with the code. I can figure out rest on my own.